# Converting iptables ruleset to Firewalld

Tags: iptables, firewall, firewalld

Does anyone have a good resource or suggestion of how to convert an iptables rule set to firewalld? I'm migrating Centos 6 to Centos 7 (actually Oracle Linux 9 but let's pretend Centos 6). I could install iptables and import rule set to new server, but it's not that simple as server server IP's have changed. The rule set in total is 70 lines....

Suggestions? Or should i just learn iptables?

Comment: To make an overly broad generalization: everyone is bad about maintaining firewall rules and most people are much more conservative (not to say lax) in removing existing rules than they are in adding new rules. A server migration is *the moment* to review your security ***policy*** and rather than migrating the existing rules start fresh with describing what you really know you need and then define that in firewalld (and yes learning both iptables and firewalld is probably a good thing)

Comment: Or describe your firewall rules in a configuration management system and let it handle configuring the firewall.

Comment: That's a very solid point. The servers and tech I've inherited more or less is not exactly cutting edge. So you're right, it's def time to review our ancient rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

disable firewalld and continue to use the old iptables and ip6tables services. This would allow you to keep the existing firewall rules. Copy the iptables-save export and load it with iptables-restore.

use given below link manual https://www.heficed.com/tutorials/vps/how-to-configure-iptables/

OR

Just create a new configuration with firewall-cmd or firewall-config.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll def look more into this.